# Adding pch on ROC curves and labelling AUC values

Tags: r, legend, roc, auc

I want to plot ROC curves for 5 estimated models using R's `pROC` application. Because I'm using gray scales, which may look indistinguishable visually, so I want to accentuate different line types by assigning different `pch` to different ROC curves, however, I found the `lines()` function is quite unresponsive to `pch` options.

Also, when I want to label their respective AUC values, using the `print.auc` option, beyond the default model (Model 1), the `roc()` and `lines()` functions do seem to work. Only AUC value for the first model is shown.

It will be very appreciated if someone could point me toward some feasible ways to achieve the desired result. Below is my current code for the plot and output.

```
### load the data ###
library(readxl)

dataURL <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/vri9fx2xa1pfj7w/predict.xlsx?dl=1"
temp = tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
download.file(dataURL, destfile=temp, mode='wb')
predict <- readxl::read_excel(temp, sheet =1)

### plotting and labelling ###

library(pROC)

roc.pred2 <- roc(predict$IAC, predict$phat2, percent = TRUE, main = "Smoothing")
roc.pred3 <- roc(predict$IAC, predict$phat3, percent = TRUE, main = "Smoothing")
roc.pred4 <- roc(predict$IAC, predict$phat4, percent = TRUE, main = "Smoothing")
roc.pred5 <- roc(predict$IAC, predict$phat5, percent = TRUE, main = "Smoothing")

plot.roc(predict$IAC, predict$phat1, percent = TRUE, main = "ROC curves", add =  FALSE, asp = NA, print.auc = TRUE)

lines(roc.pred2, type = "l", lty = 2, col = "grey35")
lines(roc.pred3, type = "l", lty = 3, col = "grey48")
lines(roc.pred4, type = "l", lty = 4, col = "grey61")
lines(roc.pred5, type = "l", lty = 1, pch = 24, col = "grey76")

legend("bottomright", 
       legend = c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", "Model 4", "Model 5"), 
       col = c("black", "grey35", "grey48", "grey61", "grey76"),
       lty = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1))
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `pch` selects the *point character*. Obviously `lines` doesn’t respond to it. Use `points` instead.

Comment: It says the first argument is a list object, so it `does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

Comment: Adding `lty = c(2, 3, 4, 1)` to the legend will fix the line types in the legend

Comment: @Allan, I have updated that in my edit, thanks for reminding me that.

Comment: To do what @KonradRudolph suggests you need to do `points(roc.pred2$sensitivities, roc.pred2$specificities, pch = 2)`

Comment: Though there are so many points, it doesn't look good. You might need to do something like `points(roc.pred2$specificities[seq(1, length(roc.pred2$sensitivities), 100)],roc.pred2$sensitivities[seq(1, length(roc.pred2$sensitivities), 100)] )` so that only every hundredth point is plotted.

Comment: Fabulous! I have around 5800 data points, so this adjustment makes them more redable. Now they all work, thanks a lot @Konrad and Allan. What's left is how to label AUC values for each curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from color, there are two things you can change on a line: type (`lty`) and width (`lwd`).

```
plot.roc(predict$IAC, predict$phat1, percent = TRUE, main = "ROC curves", add =  FALSE, asp = NA, print.auc = TRUE)

lines(roc.pred2, type = "l", lty = 2, col = "grey35")
lines(roc.pred3, type = "l", lty = 3, lwd = 4, col = "grey48")
lines(roc.pred4, type = "l", lty = 4, lwd = 8, col = "grey61")
lines(roc.pred5, type = "l", lty = 1, pch = 24, col = "grey76")

legend("bottomright", 
       legend = c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", "Model 4", "Model 5"), 
       col = c("black", "grey35", "grey48", "grey61", "grey76"),
       lty = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
       lwd = c(1, 1, 4, 8, 1))
```

[image]

Besides of that, you'll reach the limits of what you can show on a black and white plot.

If you had fewer points on your ROC curve, I would suggest to use `type = "b"` which plots points and lines:

```
data(aSAH)
plot(roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$wfns), type = "b")
```

[image]

Then you can play with `pch`, `bg` and `col` on the points too. However as you noticed that's not going to work for you because your curve has too many points.